# Job fails on loading com.databricks.spark.csv in SparkR shell

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

When I open the sparkR shell like below I am able to run the jobs successfully

```
>bin/sparkR
>rdf = data.frame(name =c("a", "b"), age =c(1,2))
>df = createDataFrame(sqlContext, rdf)
>df
DataFrame[name:string, age:double]
```

Wherease when I include the package spark-csv while loading the sparkR shell, the job fails

```
>bin/sparkR --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3
>rdf = data.frame(name =c("a", "b"), age =c(1,2))
>df = createDataFrame(sqlContext, rdf)


> rdf = data.frame(name =c("a", "b"), age =c(1,2))
> df = createDataFrame(sqlContext, rdf)
15/06/25 17:59:50 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collectPartitions at NativeMe
thodAccessorImpl.java:-2
15/06/25 17:59:50 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (collectPartitions at NativeMetho
dAccessorImpl.java:-2) with 1 output partitions (allowLocal=true)
15/06/25 17:59:50 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0(collectPartition
s at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
15/06/25 17:59:50 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
15/06/25 17:59:50 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
15/06/25 17:59:50 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (ParallelCollectio
nRDD[0] at parallelize at RRDD.scala:453), which has no missing parents
15/06/25 17:59:50 WARN SizeEstimator: Failed to check whether UseCompressedOops
is set; assuming yes
15/06/25 17:59:50 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(1280) called with curMem=0,
maxMem=280248975
15/06/25 17:59:50 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory
 (estimated size 1280.0 B, free 267.3 MB)
15/06/25 17:59:50 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(854) called with curMem=1280
, maxMem=280248975
15/06/25 17:59:50 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in
memory (estimated size 854.0 B, free 267.3 MB)
15/06/25 17:59:50 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on l
ocalhost:55886 (size: 854.0 B, free: 267.3 MB)
15/06/25 17:59:50 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGSc
heduler.scala:874
15/06/25 17:59:50 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage
 0 (ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at RRDD.scala:453)
15/06/25 17:59:50 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
15/06/25 17:59:50 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, lo
calhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1632 bytes)
15/06/25 17:59:50 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
15/06/25 17:59:50 INFO Executor: Fetching http://172.16.104.224:55867/jars/org.a
pache.commons_commons-csv-1.1.jar with timestamp 1435235242519
15/06/25 17:59:50 INFO Utils: Fetching http://172.16.104.224:55867/jars/org.apac
he.commons_commons-csv-1.1.jar to C:\Users\edwinn\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-39ef1
9de-03f7-4b45-b91b-0828912c1789\userFiles-d9b0cd7f-d060-4acc-bd26-46ce34d975b3\f
etchFileTemp3674233359629683967.tmp
15/06/25 17:59:50 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1012)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:
702)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:873)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:853)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:465)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor
$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:398)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor
$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:390)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(
TraversableLike.scala:772)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.sca
la:98)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.sca
la:98)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala
:226)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.s
cala:771)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor
$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/06/25 17:59:50 **WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localh
ost): java.lang.NullPointerException**
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1012)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:
702)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:873)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:853)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:465)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor
$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:398)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor
$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:390)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(
TraversableLike.scala:772)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.sca
la:98)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.sca
la:98)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala
:226)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.s
cala:771)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor
$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:390)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:193
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/06/25 17:59:50 ****
15/06/25 17:59:50 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have
all completed, from pool
15/06/25 17:59:50 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
15/06/25 17:59:50 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (collectPartitions at NativeM
ethodAccessorImpl.java:-2) failed in 0.156 s
15/06/25 17:59:50 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: collectPartitions at NativeMe
thodAccessorImpl.java:-2, took 0.301876 s
15/06/25 17:59:50 **ERROR RBackendHandler: collectPartitions on 3 failed
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.handleMethodCall(RBackendHandl
er.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.s
cala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.s
cala:36)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChanne
lInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(Abst
ractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(Abstra
ctChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToM
essageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(Abst
ractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(Abstra
ctChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessage
Decoder.java:163)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(Abst
ractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(Abstra
ctChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChanne
lPipeline.java:787)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(Abstra
ctNioByteChannel.java:130)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.jav
a:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEve
ntLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.ja
va:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThread
EventExecutor.java:116)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorato
r.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Ta
sk 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.
0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1012)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:
702)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:873)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:853)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:465)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor
$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:398)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor
$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:390)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(
TraversableLike.scala:772)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.sca
la:98)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.sca
la:98)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala
:226)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.s
cala:771)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor
$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:390)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:193)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DA
GScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1266)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(D
AGScheduler.scala:1257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(D
AGScheduler.scala:1256)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.
scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala
:1256)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$
1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$
1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGSchedu
ler.scala:730)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAG
Scheduler.scala:1450)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAG
Scheduler.scala:1411)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
**Error: returnStatus == 0 is not TRUE**
>
```

I get the above error. Any Suggestions? Thanks.[image: Job Details]

I haven't used any cluster. I've set

```
>bin/SparkR --master local --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3
```

My OS version is Windows 8 Enterprise, Spark 1.4.1, Scala 2.10.1, Spark-csv 2.11:1.0.3/2.10:1.0.3

Comment: Could you add some more details on the cluster type / OS you are using ? The --packages flag adds a dependency which Spark is trying to fetch. However the code to fetch the JAR file (`fetchFile` in the stack trace) is failing for some reason.

Comment: What might be the possible reasons for fetchFile failure? Even i'm getting the same exception.