# SparkR can't load data into R

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I followed the exact the same steps from other posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870379/loading-com-databricks-spark-csv-via-rstudio/30909511#30909511) to create a spark dataframe in R.

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "E:/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6")
Sys.setenv('SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS'='"--packages" "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0" "sparkr-shell"')
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_60")
library(rJava)
library(SparkR, lib.loc = "E:/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6/R/lib/")
sc <- sparkR.init(master = "local", sparkHome = "E:/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6")
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, iris)
```

However, it keeps giving me the error at the very last step:

> Error in invokeJava(isStatic = FALSE, objId$id, methodName, ...) :
>         org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:873)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:853)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:381)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:405)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:397)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:7